# How to build and train a sequence 2 sequence model in tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js, sequence-to-sequence

Hi I am trying to build a text summarizer, using sequence 2 sequence model in tensorflow.js.

My dataSet(example) :

```
{
Text: i want to return this product because it was broken when i received it.
Expected Output: broken Product.
}
```

I can convert text to word vectors using a pre-trained word2vec model.
I am using these word embeddings for an LSTM network to get a sentiment value.

I could get some sense of sequence 2 sequence model theoretically, but i could not wrap my head around this idea interms of coding, how an encoder/decoder network looks like as a real code.

Can any please post a straight and a simple example of encoder and decoder network in tensorflow.js.

Or if there are any examples already posted some where that you know can you share them please.

Comment: The problem with encoder/decoder networks in tfjs is, that it's not that simple to get output of a layer which is inside the network. The only way I can think of is to get all the weights of the layers before and build a new model out of it.

Comment: I didn't get you can you explain a little bit more ? Thank you.

Comment: Each tf.sequential in tfjs only has one output layer, so if you train your network on en-/decoding, the same network can't just encode, because the inner layer outputs aren't valid outputs. But maybe you can use the more flexible tf.model to create a network that has multiple outputs.

Comment: can you share a code example or some resource that i can look at please.